# SQL - How to calculate total without using UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a table with the data that looks like this but without using `UNION` in my query.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Parent ID | Name              | # of Record |
+---------------------------------------------+
| NULL      | Peter             | 8           |
| 1         |  - Jack           |   6         |
| 1         |  - James          |   2         |
+---------------------------------------------+
| NULL      | Jessica           | 9           |
| 2         |   - Bob           |   2         |
| 2         |   - Patrick       |   4         |
| 2         |   - Shawn         |   3         |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

The first query it returns Peter and Jessica with their total by using `SUM()` of `COUNT()` of the column `# of Record`.
The second query I use count `COUNT()` without `SUM()` and finish with `UNION` to get the result I want

Comment: Please add the queries you are using and provide a sample of what the output should look like.

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY whatever WITH ROLLUP` ?

Comment: I am not too familiar with it but I am reading on it right now. I think I found what I need. :-)